# How do i clone an old commit into a new repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I used git to track changes in a project. The first couple of commits were all about setting up the environment and including a bunch of plugins to get a bare framework.

How do i start a new project starting from one of the old commits from my existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `git archive`:

```
git archive --format=zip --prefix MyNewProj/ <oldcommit> -o ../basicproject.zip
cd ..
unzip basicproject.zip
cd MyNewProj
git init
```

This will create a zip archive of all tracked files (not any ignored, like binaries) at the commit `<oldcommit>`. Then you can unzip it into a new project.

Comment: Fantastic! Just the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch from any old point:

```
git checkout -b topic <oldpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that using a zip format can be problematic on *very* large repo, depending on the unzip software used (especially on Windows).
That is what git 2.6 (Q3/Q4 2005) addresses:

See [commit 88329ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88329ca8091b16f4bb01e3ea546c8c5e1a5016ec), [commit 0f747f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f747f9d37e2b3d7a454029dfcf0065e6914e995), [commit 19ee294](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19ee29401dfc414924f335c21ef9880513f3c58d) (22 Aug 2015) by René Scharfe.
Suggested-by: Johannes Schauer .
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 565f575](https://github.com/git/git/commit/565f575791f34e9e0f8d45c4762e5ec4c44cc993), 01 Sep 2015)</sup>

> ## `archive-zip`: support more than 65535 entries
>
> Support more than 65535 entries cleanly by writing a "zip64 end of central directory record" (with a 64-bit field for the number of entries) before the usual "end of central directory record" (which contains only a 16-bit field).
>   InfoZIP's zip does the same.
>   Archives with 65535 or less entries are not affected.
>
> Programs that extract all files like InfoZIP's zip and 7-Zip ignored the field and could extract all files already.
>   **Software that relies on the ZIP file directory to show a list of contained
>   files quickly to simulate to normal directory like Windows'built-in ZIP functionality only saw a subset of the included files**.
>
> Windows [supports ZIP64 since Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#ZIP64).

Here, that should not matter, unless the commit is a very large one.